# update mouse position durng FLVPlayback

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-listener

How would you randomly move the mouse 1px while my FLVPlayback is running and stop moving the mouse when the movie ends?

I was thinking of using an eventListener that while playing the flv runs a function that updates the mouse x and y randomly. But when the move Completes it removes the moveNouse listener.

```
my_flv.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, removeMouseMove);

my_flv.addEventListener(Event.PLAYHEADUPDATE, moveMouse);

function moveMouse(){
mouseX = mouseX +1;
}

function removeMouseMove(){
removeEventListener moveMouse
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** control the cursor from Flash.

With that said, you **can** hide the cursor and then use your own graphic to represent it. This can then obviously be moved to wherever you like.

This should get you started:

[`Mouse.hide();`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#hide%28%29)

Comment: my app is fighting with an automatic screen saver that we want to kick on but not until after the video completes. The only way to keep the screen saver off is to update the mouse. Any recommendations?

Comment: Hmm not sure. By screensaver do you just mean a fullscreen flash app or an actual screensaver as set up on the PC itself?

Comment: The screen saver is part of a touchscreen software package so not much we can change on that side.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I'm not in a position where I can offer much more advice then :(